# Inserting Bunch Data - Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is my query in SQL language:

```
INSERT INTO db.server(client_id, server_id, count) 
    SELECT id, type, COUNT(*) 
    FROM db.service 
    GROUP BY id, type
```

How to convert such an insert to a LINQ (for Entity Framework) query?

Comment: LINQ in itself does not operate against a database. Are you using Entity Framework (LINQ to Entities)?

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: You would add your new entities to the context and call SaveChanges()

Comment: @Crowcoder all of the entities are available in the context. I just need to convert the query I asked into `linq`.

Comment: You typically do not do it that way with an ORM like EF. You perform your operations on the entities that are tracked by the context and then you `SaveChanges()`. You can execute raw sql with the context but that's not LINQ nor is it advisable if you don't need to.

Comment: `db.Servers.AddRange(db.Services.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Type }).Select(x => new Server() { Id = x.Key.Id, Type = x.Key.Type, Count = x.Count() }); db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @RandRandom why not to submit as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is equivalent to your query in SQL.

```
var list = db.Services
           .GroupBy(a => new { a.ID, a.Type })
           .Select(a => new Server { Client_ID = a.Key.ID, Server_ID = a.Key.Type, Count = a.Select(b => b.ID).Count() }).ToList();


//add to db
db.Servers.AddRange(list);
db.SaveChanges();
```